# "You should know" is it going beyond respect?

Tags: expression-choice

I'm going to start a informatic video series named

"#YouShouldKnow"

inspired from "Did You Know"

but I think the name is getting little harsh and disrespectful, but I am confused

Is this name Ok (with respect)? or I have to think another name to attain a respectful manner?

Comment: Well, anyone can ask a question (e.g, _Did you know ..?_), but stating obligations for what people should do is rather presumptuous, don't you think? Especially since you don't know the people who will be reading it. _`P` should `Verb`_ means that the speaker asserts that `P` has a responsibility to `Verb`, whether `P` wants to `Verb` or not -- and probly `P` **doesn't** much want to `Verb`, or they wouldn't need reminding. So, all told, it's not a promising business name, unless you have some sort of moral control over all your customers -- or are willing to assert it, anyway.

Comment: Telling people they should know something might very well put them on the defensive, which wouldn't make them as open to your ideas as a gentler title might.

Comment: Yes @JohnLawler, Nicole I agree with both of you, it is not a good business name, and it too put the viewers on defensive side.

Comment: @Nicole how about "YouMayKnow" ?

Comment: @BurgeoningIslam Yeah, I'd say that's better.

Answer (score 3):

**Counterpoint**:

The intent of a title “should” be to seize the attention and stimulate interest. Ambiguity is an established ploy of the advertising industry to “hook” one’s attention and provoke further interest. Ambiguity presents the intellectually curious with an inviting challenge, with a puzzle that must be solved. While the title may be off-putting, as presumptuous, to those blind to the ambiguity, that presumption would be, “I already know all I need to know.” Those offended by the mere suggestion that they may not “know it all” are probably not your intended demographic.

**I would probably be interested by your title. Whether or not I'd regret that initial interest would be determined by what came next.**

**Q**: *What’s your demographic?*

No matter what product you are offering you’re not going to interest everyone, so it’s helpful to get at least a rough idea of the characteristics of those who are likely to find your product interesting enough to *click* on a link, and those who are not likely to be interested at all.

Once you’ve determined your demographic you want to create a title composed of language stimulating enough to peak their interest.

The general idea in marketing is to pitch your language---that of your title, your product, and your advertisements---toward the middle of your demographic. Try to strike a linguistic balance between provocativity and magnanimity.

Comment: Agreed very much. If it's clear that this is some type of informatic thingy, my immediate interpretation of _#youshouldknow_ used as a hashtag would be “Here are some things that you probably don't know, but which it would be very beneficial for you to know”. Assuming the video lived up to that, I would find it a perfectly fine hashtag to use.

Answer (score 2):

"You should know" can have two interpretations. One would typically be seen as derogatory, indicating "common knowledge", *i.e.*, "you should already know this and I'm simply explaining something that's obvious to everyone else". The other can be seen as beneficial, indicating "obscure yet useful knowledge", *i.e.*, "you should know this because it will make some aspect of your life better".

Due to the ambiguity and the likelihood of offense, try a different name. If you're publishing "common knowledge", find a phrase that puts it into a positive light. If you're publishing "obscure yet useful knowledge", find a phrase that clarifies that and (again) puts it into a positive light.

I'm not a marketer, but I wanted to give a couple of suggestions for a well-rounded answer.

Thoughts for "common knowledge":

- Fill the gap
- Horse sense for people

Thoughts for "obscure yet useful knowledge":

- Fit square pegs in circles
- Uncommon sense

Comment: Nicely explained, its really helpful